# How to call an ajax callback function every X hours Flask

Tags: ajax, flask, callback, plotly

I'm following a tutorial where we use Ajax to create a callback in our Flask app
The tutorial creates a button where each click will call an ajax callback function.

I'd like to have the same behavior but instead of having the user clicking the button, I want the function to be called every X hours.

To be more precise : I'm plotting multiple graphs using an API but I want those graphs to be updated every hour, without having the user refreshing the page.

Here is the sample tutorial code :

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, config, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_data() :
    # suppose api calls here
    ...
    return df_data #dataframe 

@app.route('/callback', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cb():
    return gm()
   
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('chartsajax.html',  graphJSON=gm())

def gm():

    df_data = get_data()

    fig = px.line(df[df['country']=='France'], x="year", y="gdpPercap")
    
    
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    print(fig.data[0])
    #fig.data[0]['staticPlot']=True
    
    return graphJSON
```

chartsajax.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function cb() {
            $.getJSON({
                url: "/callback", success: function (result) {
                    Plotly.newPlot('chart', result, {staticPlot: true});;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="font-family:arial, sans-serif">
    <h1>GDP per Capita Over Time</h1>
    <h2>Choose your country</h2>
    <p>Make sure you spell it correctly with capital letter(s), e.g. United Kingdom</p>
    <input type="submit" id="fname" name="fname" onchange="cb()">
    <div id="chart" class="chart"></div>
</body>

<script>
    d = {{ graphJSON | safe }};
    //d.config={staticPlot: true};
    Plotly.newPlot('chart', d, {});
    
</script>
</html>
```

I know how to do it using Dash but I'd like to use Flask for this project.. As I understand, Dash is Flask + Plotly so I really don't understand why it look difficult to do..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) :

> The `setInterval()` method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces,
> repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
> time delay between each call.
>
> This method returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the
> interval, so you can remove it later by calling `clearInterval()`.

For example :

```js
const delay = 60*60*1000;
var intervalID = setInterval(cb, delay);
```